# Developing grok-style Dexterity add-ons in Plone 4.3

Tags: plone, setuptools, buildout, dexterity, grok

According to:

- http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/how-to/install

To use **grok-style** declarations in **Plone 4.3** one must install **Dexterity** via buildout with **setuptools** extras requirements: grok and relations (referring to `extras_require` definitions in plone.app.dexterity's setup.py). But what should add-on developers who want to perform this configuration on behalf of end users do?

With my [collective.project](https://github.com/collective/collective.project) add-on, I have copied the `extras_require` from plone.app.dexterity:

```
setup(
    author='Alex Clark',
    author_email='aclark@aclark.net',
    description='Demo app: project management with dexterity content types.',
    entry_points={
        'z3c.autoinclude.plugin': 'target = plone',
    },
    extras_require = {
        'test': [
            'plone.app.testing',
            'unittest2'
            ],
        'grok': [
            'five.grok',
            'plone.directives.dexterity',
            'plone.directives.form >=1.1dev',
            ],
        'relations': [
            'plone.app.relationfield',
            'plone.app.intid',
            'z3c.relationfield',
            ]
    },
```

This allows end users to install collective.project simply by adding to a list of eggs e.g.

```
[plone]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
eggs =
  Pillow
  Plone
  collective.project
```

Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: Ah, I fooled myself; the above wasn't actually working at all. I'll answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not. Do not copy the `extras_require` from plone.app.dexterity, it doesn't help (though maybe including the extras_require as install_requires would work, but that would defeat the purpose of extras_require)

However, you can use a similar syntax as Buildout uses to specify `extras_require` in **setup.py**:

```
install_requires=[
    'setuptools',
    'plone.app.dexterity[grok]',
],
```

Comment: Of course, you should only do that if your add-on actually requires grok and relations support.

Comment: Right. According to the install manual: "adding plone.app.dexterity to your eggs no longer enables the grok-style configuration or relation field features by default." and since I don't need relations field support I should leave that out. I'll edit.

Comment: Could you accept your answer as the correct one? Should be possible now as a couple of days have passed